# node.js - does anyone know how to 'require()' external modules in _third_party_main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When using `_third_party_main.js` to extend node with your own script, when running your code in this context it seems that you can only require modules that are build in the node binary executable.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Normally, a Node.js module only exposes the module.exports object to external code

Comment: you can also refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449485/node-js-native-module-third-party-main-not-working

Comment: No, I don't have problem with loading _third_party_main.js, or any other *.js file that I put in lib/ to build with node. I can't load any external stuff in _third_party_main.js like 'require("mongoose")'.

Comment: Having the same problem and can't seem to find a solution - has anyone ever been able to solve this?  Is there a way I can just package my node_modules directory when building node?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you put your_stuff_file.js in root directory, just use require('./your_stuff_file.js').
Of course, your stuff must be referenced using module.exports.

Comment: Yes, that works, also to point out I've used urequire to combine all my files in to a single js file without the dependencies, because mongodb depends on some native modules (kerberos.node and bson.node) which are not written in javascript, and therefore must be loaded externally. Also the error i get is: "throw new Error('No such native module ' + id);"

Comment: Kerberos and bson, which is written in C++, are compiled using node-gyp. Can you describe the problem clearer? I think my answear is quite suitable for this topic, why it isn't marked answered?

Comment: Ok, my goal is to distribute my server app as a single binary file, node allows you to put your script in "lib/_third_party_main.js" (described in greater detail here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449485/node-js-native-module-third-party-main-not-working?lq=1)) and be executed on startup. My problem is that my server app cannot load it's dependencies, it throws an error saying ex. "No such native module mongoose", it only works with build in modules like "http", or modules/files that are build in to the node binary, but you can only include javascript, not binary modules.